# How the signal thing works in Mobile

Tags: iphone, signals, samsung-mobile, nokia

In mobile how can we say that I've got 2 signal or 3 signals ? On what basis this signal thing work in mobile? I don't know how it works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe there is a built-in software in mobile phones which receives the signals and measures the strength of signal and on basis of that it shows the number of signals in mobile phones. Let me explain with an example, suppose if we are talking about Airtel Cellular Company. So Airtel have created many base-stations of towers in every cities of every states. So if we getting the signals in mobile phones that is because of base-stations. The built-in software in mobile phones receives the signals from nearest base-station and measures the strength of the signal and show the number of signal in mobile phones. This is all I found, if anyone knows better than me please add comment.

Comment: This is my opinion!